# How to detect a webpage HAS been loaded in java

Tags: java

I am using the following code to display a webpage:

```
      String downloadURL="http://in.finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=%5ENSEI#symbol=%5Ensei;range=1d;compare=;indicator=volume;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=off;source=;";
        java.awt.Desktop myNewBrowserDesktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
        java.net.URI myNewLocation = new java.net.URI(downloadURL);
        myNewBrowserDesktop.browse(myNewLocation);
```

Now , i want to detect when the page has been fully loaded. ( The wait dialog is to displayed till then ). How to do i go about doing that? 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't. Once you call browse(), if all goes well,  the operating system takes care of launching the URI in the  default browser and there is nothing (like a handle) returned to your application so it's not possible.

Comment: I hope some java people take care of it soon. Thanks Bala .